# onEdit click should bind the selected values to the input controls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I am facing issue with binding the selected value to respective control in UI. Here is the scenario. I have a dropdownlist. Based on the dropdownlist, I will render the controls to UI. When user clicks Add. I am adding it 
to an array and displaying in the UI. If user clicks remove. I am removing that particular item from the array. But now, Ihave an other functionality. When user clicks Edit button, that particular item needs to be rendered
in UI to it's respective control i.e, to dropdownlist, text box, checkbox, date picker. I am trying the following code and was  stuck how I can achieve this functionality.

Can someone help me out with this?

Here is my Typescript code:

```
export class TestClass{
Add() {
      this.finalValues.push(new SelectedList(this.selectedItemType, this.txtEntered, this.date, this.chkBox));
    }
 HandleEdit(i) {
      this.finalValues.find(i => i.attributeName);

      return false;
    }

    HandleRemove(i) {
      this.finalValues.splice(i, 1);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="col col-12 col-spacing">
  <div>
    <md-select [placeholder]="result" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemType" >
      <md-option *ngFor='let attr of result' [value]="attr.fieldType"> {{attr.attribute}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItemType =='string' || selectedItemType =='decimal' || selectedItemType == 'text' || selectedItemType == 'integer'">
    <input placeholder="Enter Text" type="text" class="input" [(ngModel)]="txtEntered">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div *ngIf="selectedItemType == 'date'" class="col col-2 col-spacing">
      <md-input-container class="datepicker-align">
        <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="startDatepicker" [(ngModel)]='date' placeholder="Select Date" name="StartDate" id="txtStrtDate"
          #startDate>
        <button id="btnOpnStartDate" mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="startDatepicker"></button>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-datepicker #startDatepicker></md-datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedItemType == 'boolean'">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="chkBox" />
  </div>
  <button *ngIf="selectedItemType" md-raised-button (click)="Add()" color="accent">Add</button>
  <md-list *ngFor='let selVal of finalValues;let i=index'>
    <md-list-item> 
      <span> {{ selVal.attributeName }} </span>
      <span *ngIf="txtEntered">{{ selVal.value }} </span>
      <span *ngIf="date">{{selVal.date}} </span>
      <span *ngIf="chkBox && !date && !txtEntered"> {{selVal.checked}} </span>  
      <a href="#" md-menu-item color="warn" (click)="HandleEdit(i)" >Edit</a>
      <a href="" md-menu-item color="warn" (click)="HandleRemove(i)">Remove</a>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</div>
```

Here is my model class

```
export class SelectedList {
    constructor(
        public attributeName: any,
        public value: any,
        public date: any,
        public checked: boolean
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems like you are looking for something like this (also, you don't have to return something from a method unless you really intend to) ,

```
export class TestClass{
Add() {
      this.finalValues.push(new SelectedList(this.selectedItemType, this.txtEntered, this.date, this.chkBox));
    }
 HandleEdit(i) {
      this.selectedItemType = this.finalValues[i].attributeName;
      this.txtEntered = this.finalValues[i].value;
       this.date = this.finalValues[i].date;
       this.chkBox = this.finalValues[i].checked;
    }

    HandleRemove(i) {
      this.finalValues.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

I hope this will give you the basic idea at least for extracting the right element from the `finalValues` list and manipulate its contents to achieve the desired effect on Edit click.